cmake failing without error messages when importing libraries after moving from single CMakeFile to a subdirectory structure
I have the following CMakeLists.txt file which configures and builds just fine.
cmake_minimum_required      (VERSION 3.22)
project                     (foo)

add_library                 (pglib SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties       (pglib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/postgres16/lib/libpq.so)
target_include_directories  (pglib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/postgres16/include)
target_link_directories     (pglib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/postgres16/lib)
target_link_libraries       (pglib INTERFACE pq)

add_executable              (bar main.cpp)
target_include_directories  (bar PUBLIC ./)
target_link_libraries       (bar PUBLIC pglib)

if I replace postgres16/include with postgres16/blabla, then I get a configuration error and I cannot even try to build. That is what I want, obviously.
Now I separate the CMakeLists.txt file into two different ones in two different directories which I combine via add_subdirectory in a third CMakeLists.txt. My directory structure is as follows:
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── postgres16
│       └── ...
└── postgres_test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp

./CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required      (VERSION 3.22)
project                     (foo)
set                         (CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS TRUE)
add_subdirectory            (lib)
add_subdirectory            (postgres_test)

lib/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required      (VERSION 3.22)

add_library                 (pglib SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties       (pglib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/postgres16/lib/libpq.so)
target_include_directories  (pglib INTERFACE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/postgres16/include)
target_link_directories     (pglib INTERFACE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/postgres16/lib)
target_link_libraries       (pglib INTERFACE pq)

postgres_test/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required      (VERSION 3.22)
add_executable              (bar main.cpp)
target_include_directories  (bar PUBLIC ./)
target_link_libraries       (bar PUBLIC pglib)

Now I configure via mkdir build; cd build; cmake .. and I see something wired. No error messages, remember that I replaced include with blabla?
So I fix the blabla, reconfigure and compile via cmake --build . --target all. Now I get missing includes.
grep postgres16 compile_commands.json shows nothing, which means that target_include_directories where not honored as before when everything was in one CMakeLists.txt.
BTW, other error messages are emitted. For e.g. if I replace target_include_directories(bar INTERFACE ...) with target_include_direcoties(bar PUBLIC...) then I do get the error message that I need to use INTERFACE.
So my three questions are:

why no error message for non existing include path when using target_include_directories in subdirectory?
why no warning message when target_include_directory is ignored for some reason?
why are target_include_directories ignored in the first place when using add_subdirectory?

@Alan Birtles, here are the compile commands you asked for:
[
{
  "directory": "/home/patrick_f/ttt/build/postgres_test",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/home/patrick_f/ttt/postgres_test/.  -o CMakeFiles/bar.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/patrick_f/ttt/postgres_test/main.cpp",
  "file": "/home/patrick_f/ttt/postgres_test/main.cpp",
  "output": "postgres_test/CMakeFiles/bar.dir/main.cpp.o"
}
]


target_include_directories doesn't check the directory exists. what are the compiler commands being used?

When you move add_library (pglib SHARED IMPORTED) into lib/CMakeLists.txt, the target pglib becomes local to that script. That is, linkage target_link_libraries (bar PUBLIC pglib) in postgres_test/CMakeLists.txt uses not an IMPORTED target, but a plain library name pglib. So CMake doesn't check correctness of the target's include directories.

@Tsyvarev, is there a logic for this behavior or is cmake trying to be surprising as can be? What workaround do yo suggest where the user does not need to know that it is an imported target (the user being the author of the second CMakeLists.txt)

Not sure about which "surprise" you are talking about: This behavior is documented in the description of add_library command. If you want the IMPORTED target to be globally visible, then add GLOBAL keyword to add_library call.

@Tsyvarev, yeah the GLOBAL was missing. Now it works. Thanks for that!
